# How Many Circuits Should I Add Upstairs?

Tags: electrical

I bought a single-family dwelling in the USA last year with this scenario on the 2nd floor:

**Circuit #1 - 15 Amp**

- Bathroom lights
- Living area (395 sq ft) lights & 7 duplex receptacles.
- Attic lights

**Circuit #2 - 15 Amp**

- Bathroom GFCI
- Bedroom (175 sq ft) with 4 duplex receptacles.
- Staircase lights
- Smoke alarms

This is barely adequate for lights and office equipment.  When I want to clean the 2nd floor, I have to be careful about where I plug in the vacuum to avoid lights flickering and UPS transfers.  Heaven forbid someone might use a hair dryer or a laser printer.

**Goals**

- New 20 Amp circuit for office equipment.
- New 15 Amp circuit dedicated to the existing bathroom loads.
- Occasional use of a vacuum, radiator, or similar load.
- Consider future needs.

At first, I thought 1 or 2 new circuits would be perfect, but I'd like to know how other folks would approach this.

Comment: you will need matching cables/wires for 20 A. You probably have 14/3 now. You can not just change the circuit breaker.

Comment: Think bathroom outlet circuits have to be 20 amps now with GFCI, and just for the bathroom(maybe mistaken).  Changing older 100w lights to LEDs will help also.

Comment: @Ruskes, yes, I have good access from the attic to run a new cable all the way to a new wall outlet.

Comment: Great then do it, I think a 12/3 would be good for that

Comment: @crip659 Good point.  I was thinking I could re-use the 14/2 bathroom cable but forgot about 210.11(C)(3)

Comment: @Ruskes Not sure where you get 14/3 from. No indication of MWBC.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact from the TLA

Comment: @Ruskes Not sure what you are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For current (US NEC) code, you need the bathroom "countertop" outlets on a 20A dedicated circuit  (technically it can serve 2 different bathrooms, but it can't serve anything else, and why share it if you don't have to?) It can serve the lights and fan in the bathroom if it's not shared and the fan is not a "heater fan."

There's a formula for required circuits elsewhere based on square footage, but that's for the minimum. You can, and probably should given your use, have more.

You have 14.25 A of "lighting" load (at 3VA per square foot) for your 395+175 square feet. According to the NEC, that (1 15A circuit, plus the 20A for the bathroom) also covers your "convenience outlets" - i.e. all the associated receptacles. But, you didn't give the square footage of the hallway, stairs and attic, which all would add to it. Technically, I think it's supposed to be the square footage of the **outside** measurement of your second floor. And, I suppose, the outside measurement of your attic, since circuits are shared.

I'd put all the lights and the smoke alarms on one of your 15A circuits, and run 3 new 20A circuits (the required bathroom circuit, and 3 of the living area + 2 of the bedroom outlets on one, 4 of the living area and 2 of the bedroom on the other) - possibly 1 more, depending on the draw and location of your laser printer/"office equipment"...

If you don't want to re-wire **all** the receptacles for 20A circuits, other than as required, bring 2 20A circuits (bathroom and "office" equipment) and divide up the outlets you don't move onto 20A circuits on your 15A circuits existing, and/or bring another 15A as well.

I'm most comfortable (code does not care) with all the lights off on a circuit by themselves, since nobody can plug anything in to that circuit to trip it, so trips leaving you in the dark will be very rare indeed. The smokes go with it because you'll notice the lights not working and they also are a load that does not "plug in" so again, very unlikely to have trips other than for a serious problem. I'd include the bathroom light and fan (if any) on that as well, unless adding in all that square footage actually got you too close to the limit for 1.

Comment: 7.6 VA?  Like 8 Watts?

Comment: typo. Just A. Editing. Fixed. Typos happen.

Comment: Just a curiosity but I think 220.11 excludes attics.  Also not getting this 7.6 A thing.  Would the math be 570 x 3 / 120 ?

Comment: Typo on the calculator, too, indeed. Might as well get the square footage as measured for the outside of th building, wcih probably means you'll find the 2 15A circuits you have are indeed the minimum that would have been required before bathrooms had to be dedicated 20A...must be time to hit the hay.

Comment: Going with this answer.  Good summary of the options.  Now I have to figure out if I can fish a new cable into the old GFCI box or would I end up replacing the box or just leaving that as-is and adding new circuits.  Going to be fun.

Answer (score 2):

> When I want to clean the 2nd floor, I have to be careful about where I plug in the vacuum to avoid lights flickering and UPS transfers.

### Whoa, whoa, whoa, that is NOT normal and requires an emergency response from you.

What overloaded circuits *should* do is act completely normal until SNAP! the circuit breaker trips.

The flickering and UPS cutout is indicating **series arc faulting** in your circuit.  This is due to a poor connection which is making a tremendous amount of heat in your walls. This is a fire hazard and must be located and eliminated!

There's at least a 98% chance that this is happening at the end of the wire, either at a socket, wire nut or switch.  So it's not happening "in the walls".  Since Code requires every splice to happen in a junction box, and every junction box to remain accessible without taking apart the building, finding and fixing this is usually straightforward.

If the wire is aluminum that is not the end of the world, but certain specific methods must be used for that to be safe.

### Add as many circuits as you like.

See all the stuff Ecnerwal says.

The hard part is finding the cable route, once that's found, 1 2 or 3 cables is about the same amount of work.

A 20 amp circuit has 2400 watts available.  A 15A circuit has 1800 watts available.  Many plug-in appliances use the "max available" to a plug-in appliance, of 1500 watts.  That includes:

- space heaters e.g. radiator heaters
- laser printers
- hair dryers (these can sometimes be as high as 1800W)

If you're following the math here, you can see that 2 of those on the same circuit is impossible. Plan your circuits accordingly.

Comment: Motor switching and printer warm-up can cause some line noise on a 14 ga cable even without arcing.  So it's possible, but doesn't have to be an emergency.  It's an inconvenience and an inadequacy at this point.  Good point about running a few cables.  I was thinking the same way, that 2 or 3 cables would be better than the 12/3 comment from above.

Comment: @RobertChapin */skeptical* I think you're rationalizing, because you don't want to deal with the problem.  I myself have a cheapie LED that flickers when the fridge starts...  but the red flag that got me out of my chair was the UPS cutting out.  That is serious. That is a fire starter.